# ImageView displayed only in some devices

Tags: android, imageview

I just noticed that an ImageView of my app only appear on some devices.
This is my simple ImageView:

```
....
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/reaction"
        android:id="@+id/img_react"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
.....
```

In some devices the image is just invisible....
The app is in the play store and so the code is obfuscated (I don't know if can be related to this).
All the other ImageView and item in my app work fine, is just this image...
Anyone have some ideas on this strange bug?

Answer (score 1):

app:srcCompat will fail prior to Lollipop.

Please refer this: 
http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html

Comment: The problem is on device with 5.0 and 6.0 too

Comment: Did you add vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true to gradle?

Comment: yes but i just resolved resizing the image. I don't know why some devices even the newest couldn't show it and maybe an oldone with less screen size and resources can.... Strange but now seems fixed.